# Erro ao conectar o php com MySQL - Connection failed: No route to host

Tags: php, mysql

Olá tenho um site php onde ele acessa o banco de dados Mysql tudo funcionava perfeitamente ate hoje a tarde quando do nada ele começou a me trazer o erro sempre que tenta acessar o mysql Connection failed: No route to host, não mexi em nada no codigo e ela fica dando erro, o mesmo codigo acessa outros servidores sem problema pelo mesmo site mas apenas esse servidor não funciona, não sei o que fazer um detalhe se eu rodar o php de outra maquina com um ip diferente do meu ele funciona normal para acessar o servidor. Não sei se tem alguma coisa bloqueando. o servidor que estou acessando não é local segue aqui um exemplo do meu codigo

```
<?php

$host = "123.123.123.123:5600";
$user = "abc";
$pass = "123456";
$base = "tec";

$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi($host, $user, $pass, $base);
if($mysqli_connection->connect_error){
   echo "Desconectado! Erro: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
}else{
   echo "Conectado!";
}
?>
```

Me ajudem não sei o que mais posso fazer, só tenho problemas em um servidor em especifico o resto está normal

Answer (score -1):

Eu creio que se utilizar de PDO haverá mais chances de dar certo, tente alterar para a porta 127.0.0.1 e veja se funciona, após isso verifique se o servidor 123 está corretamente declarado.

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=tec";
$root = "abc";
$password = "123456";

$con = new PDO($dsn,$root,$password) OR DIE ('Erro na conexão!');

if($con){
   //code...
}
else {
   //code...
}
?>
```

Comment: O servidor não é local como mencionado no anuncio

Comment: De uma olhada nessa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57001170/mysql-connection-failed-no-route-to-host se trata de um problema parecido.

Comment: Se estiver usando Linux tente esse caminho: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-route-to-host-error-linux/

Answer (score -2):

O problema não parece estar no seu código, mas sim no servidor SQL ou em algum intermediário.

1. Cheque se o serviço está rodando
2. Cheque se o número da porta está correta ou se o firewall está bloqueando a porta
3. Cheque se o seu computador consegue acessar o ip (use um ping para checar isso)
4. Se tiver algum roteador no meio do caminho, cheque o firewall do roteador ou o port forwarding

espero ter ajudado